# Adding elements in Biztalk Expression Editor

Tags: biztalk

I have an orchestration that sends out emails and I'm trying to write out the email subject to include nodes from the XML. I want to write the following in the subject:
EDI 860 - PO Change Notification:(Buyer Name),(Buyer City),(Buyer State)

This is how I wrote it in the expression:

```
emailSubject = "EDI 860 - PO Change Notification:"+"/*[local-name()='Name' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='buyer_name' and namespace-uri()='']"+"/*[local-name()='Name' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='city' and namespace-uri()='']"+"/*[local-name()='Name' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='state' and namespace-uri()='']";
```

Is this correct? I'm pretty new to orchestrations and writing expressions. I didn't get any errors while writing and it seems like valid language, but I don't have a test environment to try it out on. I'm worried that the email will currently come out like this:

EDI 860 - PO Change Notification:(Buyer Name)+(Buyer City)+(Buyer State)

Answer (score 1):

For starters. Get a test environment or at the very least test it in your dev environment.  You should not release anything that has not been tested.

No, it would not work like that, see [Using XPaths in Message Assignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee268159(v=bts.10).aspx)
It would have to look like the below where you also tell it that it is an xpath and have the name of the message (msg)

```
myString = xpath(msg, "string(/*/book[1]/title)");
```

Even if it had worked it would look like the second one example, as you aren't adding the commas in the string concatenation.

Also rather than trying to use XPaths, you might want to look at using distinguished fields in your schema.  This will make it a lot easier to refer to elements in your payload and make it easier for developers to read (it still uses XPaths under the hood).

To use the distinguished field you just refer to the message name & field name

e.g.

```
emailSubject = "EDI 860 - PO Change Notification:"+ msg.Name.buyer_name + "," + msg.Name.city + "," + msg.Name.state;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Much appreciated. I added the external schema and distinguished the fields, but how do I add more than 1 distinguished field into the one Subject Field string?